# Getting 400(bad request) error in jquery ajax POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, cordova

I am trying  to send an Ajax POST  Request using jquery but I am  getting   400(bad request)error
Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://192.168.3.118:2244/api/Customer/PostTblCustomer",
       type: "POST",
    data: {"CustName":"naveen", 
    "Mobile": 9490429799, 
    "Email":"naveendodda848@gmail.com",
    "Address":"Hyderabad",
    "Password":12345, 
    "PinCode": 50000,
    "IsServiceProvider":"false",
    "Is_Blocked":"false"},

    dataType: "json",
     contentType:"application/json",

    success: function(data){
        alert("success");
        alert(data);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert("error");
      alert(thrownError);

       console.log(xhr.status)
      console.log(thrownError);
       console.log(ajaxOptions);
    }
})
```

I am new  to Phone gap Please Correct me above attached code thanks in adavance

Comment: The call works with postman or another ajax tool? Is the error showing in real devices or simulators/browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to stringify your data

```
data: JSON.stringify({"CustName":"naveen", 
    "Mobile": 9490429799, 
    "Email":"naveendodda848@gmail.com",
    "Address":"Hyderabad",
    "Password":12345, 
    "PinCode": 50000,
    "IsServiceProvider":"false",
    "Is_Blocked":"false"}),
```

Comment: Thanks are response  again i am getting  error  as  POST http://192.168.3.118:2244/api/Customer/PostTblCustomer 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @NaveenDodda Your 192.168.3.118:2244/api/Customer/PostTblCustomer page contains error